# Sending mail error

Tags: c#

I used the code shown below, and set setting in `web.config` file, but I get this error:

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at

Code:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    mail.Subject = "Demo to Semnd Message";
    mail.To.Add("sabirshaikh99@yahoo.co.in");// ("only4sabir@3sixtyit.com");
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mail.Body = "<html> <body> <div style='margin:10px;padding:5px;border:1px solid #fff000;'>" + txtMessage.Text + " </div> </body></html>";

    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
    //smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Send(mail);
}
```

`web.config` file:

```
<mailSettings>
    <smtp from="only4sabir@gmail.com" deliveryMethod="Network">
      <network defaultCredentials="false" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" password="password" userName="only4sabir@gmail.com" enableSsl="true"/>    
    </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Please check above code and give me a solution.

Comment: are you sure your credentials are correct?

Comment: defaultCredentials="false". Try setting this to true

Answer (score 1):

As documented here :- http://www.mywindowshosting.com/support/KB/a1546/send-email-from-gmail-with-smtp-authentication-but.aspx

> Send email from Gmail with SMTP authentication but got "5.5.1
>   Authentication Required" error
>
> You may get error message mentioned below when you using your gmail
>   account to send email message through your script
>
> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
>   authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.
>
> Solution:
>
> 1. Please make sure you have set SMTP authentication correctly in your script, for sample code, please click here
> 2. If there is no problem with your SMTP script, but you still got the message message mentioned above, it should because Gmail blocked
>      the authentication from our server as it detected that it is the first
>      time you login to your Gmail account from another Country or Location.
>      You will need to login to gmail security center to approve the
>      authntication. Once you approved it , please wait a few minutes then
>      sending email from script again. Here are the steps to approve the
>      "Unusual activity alerts" from gmail security center.
>      a) go to gmail
>      security center via this link blow or google search for "gmail
>      secrity" and login with your gmail account 
>      https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?elo=1
>      b) next to "security"
>      / "Recent activity" , click to "view all events"
>      c) You will able to
>      see "Unusual Activity" , it will show all unusual activity events,
>      select related event and approval it via click " Yes, That was me!"

Answer (score 0):

The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at

Solutions:

1.Disable ur gmail account second verification code.then only a secure mail can send to the client.otherwise the verification code will block the mail sending activity.

2.defaultCredentials="false"

3.Try this simple method
[Sending mail through C# And Asp.net](https://rajeeshmenoth.wordpress.com/2014/07/31/how-to-send-a-email-using-asp-net-c/)